# How to run XNA framework game without installing Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, xna

I have a steam game that uses Microsoft XNA framework. This has a dependency on some Windows Media Player (WMP) dlls. For some reason I'm unable to reinstall WMP via "Turn windows features on or off" ("An error has occurred. Not all of the features were successfully changed").

Answer (score 1):

Hacky work-around:

1. Search for `wmp.dll` in `C:\Windows\WinSxS\`. They should be in a folder `C:\Windows\winSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-mediaplayer-core_*\*`
   E.g. `wow64_microsoft-windows-mediaplayer-core_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.15063.0_none_26d246aabc4934f8`
2. Copy `wmp.dll` and `wmploc.dll` to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (or `C:\Windows\system32` if using 32bit Windows). 
   **Note**: For newer versions additional files might have to be included: `wmp.dll`, `wmploc.dll`, `dxmasf.dll` and `gnsdk_fp.dll`
3. Open `cmd` as admin
4. In `cmd` window enter `regsvr32 c:\windows\syswow64\wmp.dll` (or `regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\wmp.dll` if 32bit Windows).
5. A "Succeeded" message should appear.
6. Start the game.

Comment: Worked for me, however it's better to avoid using search, just navigate in the folder yourself as there are several versions of that file and some are 32bits, which will pop an error message in cmd

Comment: Scratch that, not working anymore

Comment: =(. Sorry for the Christmas surprise! Alas, after 5 years the game likely needs some sort of emulation.

Comment: You also need 2 more files, I'll edit your answer